# calling update of class extending JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, updates

I have a class A which extends JPanel and overrides paintComponent method. Now I have another class B which creates an object of Class A. Now how to call update method of A from B ? a method which just updates graphic and doesn't draw from start.

even when i'm calling update(Graphics g) method Of JLabel (class A object) it draws from new and doesn't keep old objects.

code snippet for class A:

```
class MyLabel extends JLabel 
{
int[] x,y;
int total;
MyLabel(ImageIcon i)
{
    super(i);
    total=0;
}

@Override 
public void update(Graphics g)
{
    super.update(g);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(total!=0)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawPolygon(x, y, total);
    }

}

public void setPoints(int xx[], int yy[], int tt)
{
    total = tt;
    x = new int[tt];
    y = new int[tt];
    System.arraycopy(xx, 0, x, 0, tt);
    System.arraycopy(yy, 0, y, 0, tt);
}
}
```

And this is code snippet from Class B.

```
sf.map_label.setPoints(x,y,total);
sf.map_label.update(sf.map_label.getGraphics());
sf.map_label.setVisible(false);
sf.map_label.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `myAObject.update()`? I really don't understand where you're stuck. If you have a reference to object A,  you simply call the A methods on this reference.

Comment: Please don't make us guess at all of this. Please put in the effort to ask a *clear* question.

Comment: Remember to call it on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to repaint without having the program clear everything and redraw it all, but only redraw the parts that have changed?

Comment: even when i'm calling update(Graphics g) method Of JLabel it draws from new and doesn't keep old objects.

Comment: Define "keep old objects". What objects are you talking about??

Comment: Calling `super.paintComponent()` at the start of A's `paintComponent()` method clears the screen of everything on it and sets it to whatever background color that has been specified by `setBackground()`. If you don't want it to clear, then make it so that `super.paintComponent()` is called only on the first time that A's `paintComponent()` is called.

Comment: I have added above my code snippets

Comment: *"I have added above my code snippets"*  For better help sooner, post one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks Jon W. handling super.paintComponent helped...